# In Windows how can I remove a word of all my folders' name?

Tags: windows, batch, rename

I have lots of folders (more than 500) that their name ends with a specific word. How can remove all of them at once?

Comment: Use a `FOR /F` loop and a `DIR` command maybe with `/S /B /A-D` parameters.... Starting point so get to trying and [edit] back what you try code wise and what you have trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove last few names then you can do the following.
Just make a .bat file from the following code and copy to the folder where you want to execute it. Run it. This example is for renaming the folder so that the first 8 characters are preserved. If you want more or less you can change as you desire.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%A in (*) do (
  set "folder=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!folder!" "!folder:~0,8!"
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: That approach wouln't work with varying file name length. To account for that use depending on the length of the appendix `ren "%%A" "!folder:~0,-8!"` for 8 chars to remove